# Why not start rabbitmq-server?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Good evening. Faced with the problem: at some point the message broker "floating" (stopped updating the web interface and make the connection). When you try to restart rabbitmq-server start command process stops responding after the message output:

```
RabbitMQ 3.6.6. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL. See www.rabbitmq.com
Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@dbserver.log
/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@dbserver-sasl.log
Starting broker...
```

Prompt, as fixed a?

P.S. Command `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service` printed:

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker.       
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-12-11 15:11:24 UTC; 15s ago
Process: 2872 ExecStop=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2795 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=73)
Main PID: 2795 (code=exited, status=73)
Status: "Processing port mapping requests..."

Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: no other nodes on dbserver
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: * suggestion: start the node
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: current node details:
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-41@dbserver'
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: - home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: - cookie hash: /637Yxskpg6/iDHKRZfS8g==
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't verify if exit code `status=73` means exactly this, for me this issue turned out to be running out of disk space. If you check the rabbitmq logs (`/var/log/rabbitmq/`), it should give you more context if this is a different error.